# Changing variable inside if blocks in .bat/.cmd programs

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I was designing a simple program in .bat (btw, is .bat the same as DOS?) that would have the user guess at the X-value of a quadratic, and I ran into a problem, namely, a missing operand error as indicated by the comment in the code below.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:top
set /p q=Take a guess:
if %q% equ 67 (
  echo YOU GOT IT! CONGRATULATIONS! The equation was "Y=17*[X-67]*[X-67]+166"
  pause
  EXIT
)
if NOT %q% equ 67 (
  echo try again.
  ::The problem is definitely in the line below this one.
  set /a r=17*(%q%-67)*(%q%-67)+189
  echo The resulting Y value is %r%
  pause
  goto top
)
```

What should I change so the program stores the correct value into r?

Comment: Here's a clarification of the terminology: **DOS** is an ancient CLI-only operating system for PCs. **cmd** is a Windows command shell that's based on DOS and is sometimes miscalled "DOS" for that reason (though not so much anymore, now that DOS has been relegated to the dustbin of history for some 15 years). **.bat** is the filename extension for batch files, which are scripts written in the "batch" language of DOS and cmd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, logically to reach the `if not %q% equ 67` statement, q must be not-67; but fixing that little flaw will disguise the problem.

You have in the if-not-67 statement

```
if NOT %q% equ 67 (
...
... bad idea to use ::-comments within a block...
set /a r=17*(%q%-67)*(%q%-67)+189
...
...
...
)
```

The problem is that the first `)` in the `set` statement is closing the `if not ...(` You'd need to escape both `)` in that `set` with a leading caret each `^)`

Your nxt problem will be that since you are setting `r` within the block [from `if not .. 67 (` to `goto top )` then you can't access its changed value with `%r%` but must use `!r!` - for which you've conveniently use `enabledelayedexpansion`  Well - actually, you could use

```
call echo The resulting Y value is %%r%%
```

but much easier to use

```
echo The resulting Y value is !r!
```

Comment: excellent, I am now slightly less of a total newbie in the world batch. Thanks.

Comment: LOL...good catch! I took a look at this and the delayed expansion issue jumped right at me...`%q%` evaluates to nothing, hence the `Missing operand` error. But I couldn't figure out why once that was fixed, it kept whining `*(!q!-67)+189 was unexpected at this time.` I know batch is ultra-lame, but I didn't realize it's so lame that it can't properly pair the parentheses of an expression within statement grouping parentheses and you have to escape the second of each pair in the expression. That transcends all bounds of lameness. But +1 to you for figuring that out. I'd give you +2 if I could!

Answer (score 0):

This Works:

```
@echo off
title written by XLR8 from http://sd-storage.weebly.com
:top
set /p q=Take A Guess
if %q%==67 goto correct
goto incorrect

:correct
echo YOU GOT IT! CONGRATULATIONS! The equation was "Y=17*[X-67]*[X-67]+166"
Echo Press Any Key To Exit
pause >nul
EXIT

:incorrect
echo try again.
goto top

set r=17*(%q%-67)*(%q%-67)+189
echo The resulting Y value is %r%
echo Press Any Key To Start Again
pause >nul
goto top
```